# Classes in a stylesheet override CDN

Tags: html, css, overriding, stylesheet, cdn

I'm using Jquery UI (Dialog to be specific)

In my CSS (local) I have my custom class for example the `input[type='text']`
In CSS there are jQuery UI customizations to the input, but they are overwriting my.

How can I always keep the most suitable as my stylesheet?

I've tried changing the order:

```
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.12/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But it always loads classes CDN.

Will not you be using !important in all classes.

Is there any way that he always give preference to my CSS file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add more [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to the CSS definition to override other definitions.

```
<style>
   div input[type=text] { ... } // more specific, higher weight
   input                { ... } // less specific than previous definition
</style>


<div>
   <input type="text" ... />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try being more specific with your query selector.  So, if your input[type=text] is in a div, say 'div input[type=text]'.  The most specific will always win.